# How to remove special characters from text file

Tags: mysql, linux, awk, sed

I've been trying to import a text file into mysql, but with no luck. I get the following error when running this command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/file' INTO TABLE test COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ':';
ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: ''
```

I found a command that was shared on here that shows me the lines with the bad characters.

```
grep -axv '.*' filename

11241321:▒oy▒_moley@zmal.com
11241771:▒om▒_shead@zmal.com
11241811:▒eva▒_gould@zmal.com
```

Now that I can tell which lines the bad characters are on then I could go delete the bad characters manually, but that's a pain because these files are potentially huge. I wonder if there is a way to find those bad characters and then delete them using the linux command line. I would like to keep the line intact, but just remove the bad character.

Comment: Load your data into temptable with one column of binary type, then use another query for to remove wrong rows and parse correct ones.

Comment: What do you want to do? Delete the strange characters, or delete the whole line if it contains a strange character?

Comment: Can you provide a text example of good v. bad? and file format? can you define what a "bad character is?" if so, then you could sed to replace of those characters will the empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove characters that are not within the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (11,12,40-176)

[image]

\11 = tab

\12 = new line

\40-176 = ( to ~ this range includes all letters and symbols present in the keyboard

```
cat test.txt | tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176' > temp && mv temp test.txt
```

NOTE: If your data has special characters that are not in the ascii table, they might be removed as well